# To set div cursor to the point of selected value of nested li

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, tree

I am working with abn tree to generate tree with some data with AngularJS html in front-end. The depth of tree is decided on run time. At first the tree will be loaded with the condition fully expanded till last level, for example when I click on : 11-B-(iii) then it expand tree as shown in pic :

Tree with selected child for text : **11-B-(iii)**

[image: Tree with selected child for text : 11-B-(iii)]

As tree is generated using abn tree, it working fine.

When it loaded for first time last element of tree shown to be selected, this has been done.

Code block :

```
<div class="col-sm-4" style="min-height:580px;max-height:600px;overflow:scroll;border:1px solid grey;">
                    <ul class="nav nav-list nav-pills nav-stacked abn-tree ng-isolate-scope" tree-data="my_data" tree-control="my_tree" on-select="vm.my_tree_handler(branch)" expand-level="10">
  <!-- ngRepeat: row in tree_rows | filter:{visible:true} track by row.branch.uid --><li ng-repeat="row in tree_rows | filter:{visible:true} track by row.branch.uid" ng-animate="'abn-tree-animate'" ng-class="'level-' + 1 + (row.branch.selected ? ' active':'')" class="abn-tree-row ng-scope level-1">
    <a ng-click="user_clicks_branch(row.branch)">
      <i ng-class="row.tree_icon" ng-click="row.branch.expanded = !row.branch.expanded" class="indented tree-icon icon-minus glyphicon glyphicon-minus fa fa-minus" role="button" tabindex="0"> </i>
      <span class="indented tree-label ng-binding">Root </span>
    </a>
  </li><!-- end ngRepeat: row in tree_rows | filter:{visible:true} track by row.branch.uid --><li ng-repeat="row in tree_rows | filter:{visible:true} track by row.branch.uid" ng-animate="'abn-tree-animate'" ng-class="'level-' + 2 + (row.branch.selected ? ' active':'')" class="abn-tree-row ng-scope level-2">
    <a ng-click="user_clicks_branch(row.branch)">
      <i ng-class="row.tree_icon" ng-click="row.branch.expanded = !row.branch.expanded" class="indented tree-icon icon-minus glyphicon glyphicon-minus fa fa-minus" role="button" tabindex="0"> </i>
      <span class="indented tree-label ng-binding">Child-I </span>
    </a>
  </li><!-- end ngRepeat: row in tree_rows | filter:{visible:true} track by row.branch.uid --><li ng-repeat="row in tree_rows | filter:{visible:true} track by row.branch.uid" ng-animate="'abn-tree-animate'" ng-class="'level-' + 3 + (row.branch.selected ? ' active':'')" class="abn-tree-row ng-scope level-3">
    <a ng-click="user_clicks_branch(row.branch)">
      <i ng-class="row.tree_icon" ng-click="row.branch.expanded = !row.branch.expanded" class="indented tree-icon icon-file  glyphicon glyphicon-file fa fa-file" role="button" tabindex="0"> </i>
      <span class="indented tree-label ng-binding">SubChild-1</span>
    </a>
  </li><!-- end ngRepeat: row in tree_rows | filter:{visible:true} track by row.branch.uid --><li ng-repeat="row in tree_rows | filter:{visible:true} track by row.branch.uid" ng-animate="'abn-tree-animate'" ng-class="'level-' + 3 + (row.branch.selected ? ' active':'')" class="abn-tree-row ng-scope level-3">
    <a ng-click="user_clicks_branch(row.branch)">
      <i ng-class="row.tree_icon" ng-click="row.branch.expanded = !row.branch.expanded" class="indented tree-icon icon-file  glyphicon glyphicon-file fa fa-file" role="button" tabindex="0"> </i>
      <span class="indented tree-label ng-binding">SubChild-2</span>
    </a>
  </li><!-- end ngRepeat: row in tree_rows | filter:{visible:true} track by row.branch.uid --><li ng-repeat="row in tree_rows | filter:{visible:true} track by row.branch.uid" ng-animate="'abn-tree-animate'" ng-class="'level-' + 3 + (row.branch.selected ? ' active':'')" class="abn-tree-row ng-scope level-3">
    <a ng-click="user_clicks_branch(row.branch)">
      <i ng-class="row.tree_icon" ng-click="row.branch.expanded = !row.branch.expanded" class="indented tree-icon icon-file  glyphicon glyphicon-file fa fa-file" role="button" tabindex="0"> </i>
      <span class="indented tree-label ng-binding">SubChild-3</span>
    </a>
  </li><!-- end ngRepeat: row in tree_rows | filter:{visible:true} track by row.branch.uid --><li ng-repeat="row in tree_rows | filter:{visible:true} track by row.branch.uid" ng-animate="'abn-tree-animate'" ng-class="'level-' + 3 + (row.branch.selected ? ' active':'')" class="abn-tree-row ng-scope level-3">
    <a ng-click="user_clicks_branch(row.branch)">
      <i ng-class="row.tree_icon" ng-click="row.branch.expanded = !row.branch.expanded" class="indented tree-icon icon-file  glyphicon glyphicon-file fa fa-file" role="button" tabindex="0"> </i>
      <span class="indented tree-label ng-binding">SubChild-4</span>
    </a>
  </li><!-- end ngRepeat: row in tree_rows | filter:{visible:true} track by row.branch.uid --><li ng-repeat="row in tree_rows | filter:{visible:true} track by row.branch.uid" ng-animate="'abn-tree-animate'" ng-class="'level-' + 3 + (row.branch.selected ? ' active':'')" class="abn-tree-row ng-scope level-3">
    <a ng-click="user_clicks_branch(row.branch)">
      <i ng-class="row.tree_icon" ng-click="row.branch.expanded = !row.branch.expanded" class="indented tree-icon icon-file  glyphicon glyphicon-file fa fa-file" role="button" tabindex="0"> </i>
      <span class="indented tree-label ng-binding">SubChild-5</span>
    </a>
  </li><!-- end ngRepeat: row in tree_rows | filter:{visible:true} track by row.branch.uid --><li ng-repeat="row in tree_rows | filter:{visible:true} track by row.branch.uid" ng-animate="'abn-tree-animate'" ng-class="'level-' + 3 + (row.branch.selected ? ' active':'')" class="abn-tree-row ng-scope level-3">
    <a ng-click="user_clicks_branch(row.branch)">
      <i ng-class="row.tree_icon" ng-click="row.branch.expanded = !row.branch.expanded" class="indented tree-icon icon-file  glyphicon glyphicon-file fa fa-file" role="button" tabindex="0"> </i>
      <span class="indented tree-label ng-binding">SubChild-6 </span>
    </a>
  </li><!-- end ngRepeat: row in tree_rows | filter:{visible:true} track by row.branch.uid --><li ng-repeat="row in tree_rows | filter:{visible:true} track by row.branch.uid" ng-animate="'abn-tree-animate'" ng-class="'level-' + 3 + (row.branch.selected ? ' active':'')" class="abn-tree-row ng-scope level-3">
    <a ng-click="user_clicks_branch(row.branch)">
      <i ng-class="row.tree_icon" ng-click="row.branch.expanded = !row.branch.expanded" class="indented tree-icon icon-file  glyphicon glyphicon-file fa fa-file" role="button" tabindex="0"> </i>
      <span class="indented tree-label ng-binding">SubChild-7 </span>
    </a>
  </li><!-- end ngRepeat: row in tree_rows | filter:{visible:true} track by row.branch.uid --><li ng-repeat="row in tree_rows | filter:{visible:true} track by row.branch.uid" ng-animate="'abn-tree-animate'" ng-class="'level-' + 3 + (row.branch.selected ? ' active':'')" class="abn-tree-row ng-scope level-3">
    <a ng-click="user_clicks_branch(row.branch)">
      <i ng-class="row.tree_icon" ng-click="row.branch.expanded = !row.branch.expanded" class="indented tree-icon icon-file  glyphicon glyphicon-file fa fa-file" role="button" tabindex="0"> </i>
      <span class="indented tree-label ng-binding">SubChild-8 </span>
    </a>
  </li><!-- end ngRepeat: row in tree_rows | filter:{visible:true} track by row.branch.uid --><li ng-repeat="row in tree_rows | filter:{visible:true} track by row.branch.uid" ng-animate="'abn-tree-animate'" ng-class="'level-' + 3 + (row.branch.selected ? ' active':'')" class="abn-tree-row ng-scope level-3">
    <a ng-click="user_clicks_branch(row.branch)">
      <i ng-class="row.tree_icon" ng-click="row.branch.expanded = !row.branch.expanded" class="indented tree-icon icon-file  glyphicon glyphicon-file fa fa-file" role="button" tabindex="0"> </i>
      <span class="indented tree-label ng-binding">SubChild-9 </span>
    </a>
  </li><!-- end ngRepeat: row in tree_rows | filter:{visible:true} track by row.branch.uid --><li ng-repeat="row in tree_rows | filter:{visible:true} track by row.branch.uid" ng-animate="'abn-tree-animate'" ng-class="'level-' + 3 + (row.branch.selected ? ' active':'')" class="abn-tree-row ng-scope level-3">
    <a ng-click="user_clicks_branch(row.branch)">
      <i ng-class="row.tree_icon" ng-click="row.branch.expanded = !row.branch.expanded" class="indented tree-icon icon-file  glyphicon glyphicon-file fa fa-file" role="button" tabindex="0"> </i>
      <span class="indented tree-label ng-binding">SubChild-10 </span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li ng-repeat="row in tree_rows | filter:{visible:true} track by row.branch.uid" ng-animate="'abn-tree-animate'" ng-class="'level-' + 3 + (row.branch.selected ? ' active':'')" class="abn-tree-row ng-scope level-3">
    <a ng-click="user_clicks_branch(row.branch)">
      <i ng-class="row.tree_icon" ng-click="row.branch.expanded = !row.branch.expanded" class="indented tree-icon icon-minus glyphicon glyphicon-minus fa fa-minus" role="button" tabindex="0"> </i>
      <span class="indented tree-label ng-binding">SubChild-11 </span>
    </a>
  </li><!-- end ngRepeat: row in tree_rows | filter:{visible:true} track by row.branch.uid --><li ng-repeat="row in tree_rows | filter:{visible:true} track by row.branch.uid" ng-animate="'abn-tree-animate'" ng-class="'level-' + 4 + (row.branch.selected ? ' active':'')" class="abn-tree-row ng-scope level-4">
    <a ng-click="user_clicks_branch(row.branch)">
      <i ng-class="row.tree_icon" ng-click="row.branch.expanded = !row.branch.expanded" class="indented tree-icon icon-file  glyphicon glyphicon-file fa fa-file" role="button" tabindex="0"> </i>
      <span class="indented tree-label ng-binding">SubSubchild-A </span>
    </a>
  </li><!-- end ngRepeat: row in tree_rows | filter:{visible:true} track by row.branch.uid --><li ng-repeat="row in tree_rows | filter:{visible:true} track by row.branch.uid" ng-animate="'abn-tree-animate'" ng-class="'level-' + 4 + (row.branch.selected ? ' active':'')" class="abn-tree-row ng-scope level-4">
    <a ng-click="user_clicks_branch(row.branch)">
      <i ng-class="row.tree_icon" ng-click="row.branch.expanded = !row.branch.expanded" class="indented tree-icon icon-minus glyphicon glyphicon-minus fa fa-minus" role="button" tabindex="0"> </i>
      <span class="indented tree-label ng-binding">SubSubchild-B </span>
    </a>
  </li><!-- end ngRepeat: row in tree_rows | filter:{visible:true} track by row.branch.uid --><li ng-repeat="row in tree_rows | filter:{visible:true} track by row.branch.uid" ng-animate="'abn-tree-animate'" ng-class="'level-' + 5 + (row.branch.selected ? ' active':'')" class="abn-tree-row ng-scope level-5">
    <a ng-click="user_clicks_branch(row.branch)">
      <i ng-class="row.tree_icon" ng-click="row.branch.expanded = !row.branch.expanded" class="indented tree-icon icon-file  glyphicon glyphicon-file fa fa-file" role="button" tabindex="0"> </i>
      <span class="indented tree-label ng-binding">SubSubSubchild-(i) </span>
    </a>
  </li><!-- end ngRepeat: row in tree_rows | filter:{visible:true} track by row.branch.uid --><li ng-repeat="row in tree_rows | filter:{visible:true} track by row.branch.uid" ng-animate="'abn-tree-animate'" ng-class="'level-' + 5 + (row.branch.selected ? ' active':'')" class="abn-tree-row ng-scope level-5">
    <a ng-click="user_clicks_branch(row.branch)">
      <i ng-class="row.tree_icon" ng-click="row.branch.expanded = !row.branch.expanded" class="indented tree-icon icon-file  glyphicon glyphicon-file fa fa-file" role="button" tabindex="0"> </i>
      <span class="indented tree-label ng-binding">SubSubSubchild-(ii) </span>
    </a>
  </li><!-- end ngRepeat: row in tree_rows | filter:{visible:true} track by row.branch.uid --><li ng-repeat="row in tree_rows | filter:{visible:true} track by row.branch.uid" ng-animate="'abn-tree-animate'" ng-class="'level-' + 5 + (row.branch.selected ? ' active':'')" class="abn-tree-row ng-scope level-5 active">
    <a ng-click="user_clicks_branch(row.branch)">
      <i ng-class="row.tree_icon" ng-click="row.branch.expanded = !row.branch.expanded" class="indented tree-icon icon-file  glyphicon glyphicon-file fa fa-file" role="button" tabindex="0"> </i>
      <span class="indented tree-label ng-binding">SubSubSubchild-(iii) </span>
    </a>
  </li><!-- end ngRepeat: row in tree_rows | filter:{visible:true} track by row.branch.uid --><li ng-repeat="row in tree_rows | filter:{visible:true} track by row.branch.uid" ng-animate="'abn-tree-animate'" ng-class="'level-' + 4 + (row.branch.selected ? ' active':'')" class="abn-tree-row ng-scope level-4">
    <a ng-click="user_clicks_branch(row.branch)">
      <i ng-class="row.tree_icon" ng-click="row.branch.expanded = !row.branch.expanded" class="indented tree-icon icon-file  glyphicon glyphicon-file fa fa-file" role="button" tabindex="0"> </i>
      <span class="indented tree-label ng-binding">SubSubchild-C </span>
    </a>
  </li><!-- end ngRepeat: row in tree_rows | filter:{visible:true} track by row.branch.uid --><li ng-repeat="row in tree_rows | filter:{visible:true} track by row.branch.uid" ng-animate="'abn-tree-animate'" ng-class="'level-' + 4 + (row.branch.selected ? ' active':'')" class="abn-tree-row ng-scope level-4">
    <a ng-click="user_clicks_branch(row.branch)">
      <i ng-class="row.tree_icon" ng-click="row.branch.expanded = !row.branch.expanded" class="indented tree-icon icon-file  glyphicon glyphicon-file fa fa-file" role="button" tabindex="0"> </i>
      <span class="indented tree-label ng-binding">SubSubchild-D </span>
    </a>
  </li><!-- end ngRepeat: row in tree_rows | filter:{visible:true} track by row.branch.uid --><li ng-repeat="row in tree_rows | filter:{visible:true} track by row.branch.uid" ng-animate="'abn-tree-animate'" ng-class="'level-' + 4 + (row.branch.selected ? ' active':'')" class="abn-tree-row ng-scope level-4">
    <a ng-click="user_clicks_branch(row.branch)">
      <i ng-class="row.tree_icon" ng-click="row.branch.expanded = !row.branch.expanded" class="indented tree-icon icon-file  glyphicon glyphicon-file fa fa-file" role="button" tabindex="0"> </i>
      <span class="indented tree-label ng-binding">SubSubchild-E </span>
    </a>
  </li><!-- end ngRepeat: row in tree_rows | filter:{visible:true} track by row.branch.uid -->
</ul>
</div>
```

Point to be noted :

- Depth of tree is not fixed. It may vary according to text clicked to load tree.
- Tree structure will not be same. It may vary according to text clicked to load tree.
- At first user will not click on any node, I just need to show scroll on top to show selected child without have to scroll.

**What I need to do ?**

I need to set cursor of div to selected element li at visible point somewhere on top of div, so that user no need to scroll till down to see the selected div. In given example tree is loaded with small number of element but actual tree will be loaded with many children and their sub children hierarchy.

I have try to get the the value and match with the string but the depth of tree is unknown to me on load. Only one thing I may know is the name of node that will be last selected, in example case : **SubSubSubchild-(iii)**

How can I set cursor of div to specific point to top to show div on top?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery is one solution.

After inspecting your code I've found that you have been using ABN tree, So what you could do is, to find the index of a li which has active class(bydefault selected in ABN tree) and set it's scrollTop property.

```
var index=$("#treeDiv ul li.active").index();
$("#treeDiv").scrollTop(index*15);
```

**NOTE**: Multiply index value by height of your each li.
Here is a [Fiddler](https://jsfiddle.net/vipulkumawat/Lm7mb06p/) which I have made based on your query.